# Componentes iguales en angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Tengo dos componentes que lucen iguales (html) pero por dentro (typescript) no hacen lo mismo.
Mi pregunta es ¿ debería ser un mismo componente o dos componentes diferentes que compartan html y css ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depende del tamaño del proyecto por que podrías provocar redundancias, la idea de angular es separar todo y tener una buena estructura

Comment: Considera leer [answer]

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]